# Add logo and slide count to the navigation symbols

Tags: beamer

I want the `navigation symbols` line (the bottom line) to contain slide count `Slide N of NN` *flushed* to the left and the company logo flushed to the right inside the blue navigation bar (I use the `Marburg` theme).

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usetheme{Marburg}
\usetheme{Marburg}
\def\mylogo{......logo.png}
\mode<handout>{
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{\parbox{\paperwidth}
    {Slide \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber{}
      \hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{\mylogo}}}}
\mode<beamer>{
  \addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}
   {Slide \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber{} \hfill}
   {\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{\mylogo}}}

\title{My Title}
\author{me}
\institute{\includegraphics[height=5mm]{\mylogo}}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{F Title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

it works perfectly for the `handout` mode, but the non-handout mode is no good:

1. the logo is in the white text area, not the blue navigation area
2. the `Slide N or NN` is flushed to the right, next to the navigation symbols, instead of being in the bottom left corner.

I read the many similar questions, but none of them answer my concerns.

Comment: Without a full example, I'd frankly consider it a waste of time to work on this. It is just way, way, way too unlikely that my attempt to construct an MWE from that fragment will be relevantly similar to your document and, therefore, way, way, way too likely that any effort I put into a solution would be of no use whatsoever.

Comment: But why add it to the navigation symbols rather than the footline?

Comment: @cfr: because I want to save screen real estate: I want the footer and the navigation to share space. Also, I made the doc complete.

Comment: Set the navigation symbol template blank and put the navigation symbols in the footline as well. I played around trying to add stuff in the same way the navigation symbols are added but gave up in the end. Somebody who knows the lower level stuff could do it, but I doubt it is the easiest way as the navigation has to be `\llap`ed and that just isn't what you want here.

Comment: @cfr: do I need to list all those nav syms _one by one_ myself in the footline? if yes, I would just drop them (they sure look nice but I don't know what they mean anyway :-)

Comment: You probably don't have to but `beamer`'s code is a bit of a maze and adding them one-by-one may well be easier than figuring out how not to have to. However, if you aren't bothered about losing them, it is pretty straightforward. I have stopped using them because I could never remember what they meant. Also, some people don't like them because they scream 'Beamer!' In my discipline, that will only be true of other eccentrics who use it, but in some subjects I guess things are different. But they are anyway really just a distraction, if not a very significant one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't bothered about the navigation symbols, you could just do this:

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usetheme{Marburg}
\def\mylogo{example-image-a}
\mode<handout>{
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{\parbox{\paperwidth}
    {Slide \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber{}
      \hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{\mylogo}}}
}
\mode<beamer>{
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{\parbox{\paperwidth}
    {Slide \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber{}
      \hfill\insertlogo}}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\makeatletter

\title{My Title}
\author{me}
\institute{\includegraphics[height=5mm]{\mylogo}}
\date{\today}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
\begin{document}
  \frame{\titlepage}
  \section{Introduction}
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{F Title}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: custom footline]